# Question about improper integrals-giving an example

Tags: calculus

Can someone give me an example of a function $f(x) $ that satisfies $ \lim_{x\to \infty} x^4 f(x) =0 $ but $\int _ {49} ^\infty f(x)dx =\infty$

Thanks ! (p.s.- the function f obviously needs to be negative in some places...But I can't find a proper example)

Comment: Why do you think such a function exists? What have you tried?

Comment: Take the zero function and around $x=50$, introduce a "spike" with infinite area.

Comment: Thanks ! but.. By trying functions like $1/(x-50)^{10} $ , I'll get that the integral exists... (and isn't infinity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{-x}}{x-49}$.

Comment: can you explain why this integral diverges?

Comment: OK Got it. Thanks !

Comment: $f(x)\ge e^{-U}/(x-49)$ when $49<x\le U$. So $\int_{49}^U f(x)dx\ge e^{-U}\int_{49}^U\frac{dx}{x-49}=\infty$. When $U$ is large and $x\ge U$, $0\le f(x)\le e^{-cx}$ for some $c<1$. So, $0\le\int_U^\infty f(x)dx<\infty$.